# Django Programming Error while runing server

Tags: django, gis

I am running a GIS application while getting this error. I have attached error snapshot . Can Someone guide where is error ? If need to see code . Let me know which file you need. [image: Programming Error /]

Comment: From the error it seems that you are missing some database columns. Did you run `./manage.py makemigrations` **and** `./manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: @nik_m I now did migrations but error is still there

Comment: thank you @nik_m I solved it .

Comment: Such kind of errors, in 99% of the time are ought to lack of `./manage migrate`. Glad I could help!

Comment: Really thank you again I was stuck from 3 hours :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially the first line of your `exception value` pretty much says it all.

```
Column users.parent_id does not exist
```

The application is trying to access `parent.id` from the `users` table from your database, which obviously does not exist. With other words, your database is not sync with the model structure in the source code. Probably all you have to do, is to run the [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) to add all the missing structures or changes to your database.

If you've developed some of the database structures yourself, you have to run the `makemigrations` command to build the new migration set for your database.

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

If you have created new migration files or if you have installed and integrated modules into your app, you have to apply the migrations to your database.

```
./manage.py migrations
```

Comment: thank you I fixed it. I should make a new column in database .